# html table td size fixed and relative mixed

Tags: html-table, width

For example,

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
     <td width="40"></td> // left margin

     <td width="10">0</td>
     <td width="%"></td>
     <td width="10">3</td>
     <td width="%">0</td>
     <td width="10">6</td>
     <td width="%">0</td>
     <td width="10">9</td>

     <td width="40"></td> // right margin
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have the fixed number column is fixed and others is relative. I tried 25% each. but still not working.

Comment: Why `10` in one td and `%` in another?

Comment: The width=10 has contents, The % is just space between contents.

Comment: It's totally wrong, learn how to create tables nicely

Comment: really? What's wrong? Any suggests for this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This `<td width="10">` should be ` <td width="10%">` and not in a separate td

Comment: I should have left margin and right margin. Then, how many % give other width? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, this is how I would structure it. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8ZPy/2/) demonstrating the code.

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

td.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 40%;
}

td.others {
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td class="fixed"></td>

     <td class="others">0</td>
     <td class="others">3</td>
     <td class="others">6</td>
     <td class="others">9</td>

     <td class="fixed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```